# Haskell: understanding partial application?

Tags: haskell, currying

I'm reading the [LYAH chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) on applicative functors, and I don't seem to understand the following example:

```
ghci> :t fmap (++) (Just "hey")  
fmap (++) (Just "hey") :: Maybe ([Char] -> [Char])
```

But when I look at this:

```
ghci> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
ghci> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I do understand how something like **(*3)** or **(++"this")** fits into the **(a -> b)** type, but I just can't see how **[a] -> [a] -> [a]** fits into **(a -> b)**?

Comment: Isn't it like that: you need to provide `(a -> b)` to `fmap`, then `f a` and it produces `f b`, so when you give `fmap` `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` then `[a] -> [a]` unifies with `(a -> b)` and `[a]` with `f a` ? I already forgot almost everything about haskell though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the stuff side-by-side as usual,

```
fmap :: Functor f => ( a    ->      b      )   ->      f a        ->   f b
fmap                       (++)                    (Just "hey")   ::   f b
(++) ::               [c]   -> ([c] -> [c])
```

So,

```
a ~ [c]  ,    b ~ ([c] -> [c])  ,    f ~ Maybe  ,    a ~ [Char]  ,   c ~ Char

f b ~ Maybe b ~ Maybe ([c] -> [c]) ~  Maybe ([Char] -> [Char])
```

No thinking is involved here. Unification of types is a mechanical process.

---

And to answer your specific question (paraphrased), *" how `[c] -> [c] -> [c]` can be matched with `a -> b`"*, here goes:

- **Omitting parentheses in type signatures is evil** (when teaching Haskell to newbies)
- In Haskell, **there are no binary functions**. Every function is unary.
- Hence (as others mentioned already), **arrows in type signatures associate to the right**.

Answer (score 7):

The key is that `->` associates to the right, so a type like `a -> b -> c` is really `a -> (b -> c)`. So `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` fits into `c -> d` by setting `c` ~ `[a]` and `d` ~ `[a] -> [a]`. You can view a function `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` either as a function of 2 arguments that returns a result of type `[a]`, or a function of 1 argument that returns a result of type `[a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 6):

The thing to realise is that the `b` in  `a -> b` doesn't have to be a scalar - it can be a function.

`[a] -> [a] -> [a]` can be thought of as `[a] -> ([a] -> [a])`, so `b` is `[a] -> [a]`

Answer (score 4):

It is simple really :-). let me add a simple parenthesis:

`[a]->[a]->[a]` is like `[a]->([a]->[a])`

So it fits in `a->b` by replacing a by `[a]` and b by `[a]->[a]`. You give a string to ++ and you get a function of type `string->string` in return

`fmap (++) (Just "hey")`  is a maybe monad holding a function which prefix the string "hey" to another string. It is indeed of type `Maybe ([Char] -> [Char])`

Answer (score 4):

Consider the definition of fmap for the Maybe type.

```
fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

which for your example looks like

```
fmap (++) (Just "Hey") = Just ("Hey" ++) :: Maybe ([Char] -> [Char])
```

As fmap should, you have simply lifted the (++) function inside the Maybe container and
applied it to the contents.